# How to change column referencing for this for loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have dummy data that I used with this script: it just updates values I put in sheet 2 and applies them with an array multiplier for wherever the `rIterators` match in sheet1. None of that is really necessary for this question, I just need to know how to update my `j` variable referencing.

Currently it is:

```
        For j = 3 To 5
            wsA.Cells(fndRow + i, j).Value = rIterator.Offset(, j - 1).Value * multplr(i)
        Next j
```

and it references columns C-E in both sheets because that's where the values align.

How would I change that if Sheet2 has the values that need to be update in columns C-E, but those columns exist in columns AD-AF in Sheet1?

Rest of code:

```
Sub UpdateTSRS()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wsA As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet
Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range
Dim rIterator As Range
Dim fndRow As Long
Dim multplr As Variant
multplr = Array(1, 1.1, 1.15, 1.2, 1.3)

Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
Set wsA = wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsB = wbk.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rngA = wsA.Range(wsA.Range("A2"), wsA.Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Set rngB = wsB.Range(wsB.Range("A2"), wsB.Range("A2").End(xlDown))

For Each rIterator In rngB
    On Error Resume Next
    fndRow = Application.Match(rIterator.Value, rngA, 0) + _
        rngA.Range("A1").Row - 1
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Else
    For i = 0 To 4
        For j = 3 To 5
            wsA.Cells(fndRow + i, j).Value = rIterator.Offset(, j - 1).Value * multplr(i)
        Next j
    Next i
        wsA.Range(wsA.Cells(fndRow, 3), wsA.Cells(fndRow, 5)).Resize(5).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    End If
    Err.Clear
Next rIterator

End Sub
```

Comment: AD = 30 (26 = z, 27 = aa, 28 = ab, 29 = ac), and go to 32 (AF)... since C is still a destination, you `Cells()` reference should indicate `+27` for AD from C and `+29` for AF from E.  if you were previously using Sheet2 (source) to Sheet1 (destination), then you want your reference to be swapped for Sheet1 (source) to Sheet2 (destination).  Essentially, change your for loop range and swap sheets for `set wsA` and `set wsB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display of code changes from my comment:

```
'Set wsA = wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
'Set wsB = wbk.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set wsB = wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsA = wbk.Sheets("Sheet2")
```

and your loop would be similar to:

```
For j = 3 To 5
    wsA.Cells(fndRow + i, j).Value = rIterator.Offset(, j +27 - 1).Value * multplr(i)  'i think i got that?  destination still C->E but source is AD->AF
Next j
```

Comment: sorry, I think I worded it poorly. The sheets aren't swapping, but Sheet1 (destination for updated values) will now have those values placed in Columns AD-AF, instead of C-E. So adding onto the offset seems to still be populating 0's in columns C-E, and doing nothing to AD-AF

Comment: whoops, just needed to flip around the +37, solved!

Comment: I mistyped, that should say +27... but you get the idea!